# Unable to login to system while recording through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm unable to record login functionality every time its giving validation message on login screen with proxy on. On removing the proxy login functionality works fine. I'm using localhost with port given with the URL of the system under test.

Address is something like - 52.xxx.xxx.xxx: Portnumber
Please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be connected with HTTPS protocol, sending username and password in plain text is a very bad practice so I am more than sure your application is using some form of [TLS encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

JMeter is able to decrypt and record secure traffic, however some extra configuration will be required, in particular you will need to add JMeter's self-signed certificate into browser so JMeter would be able to intercept secure traffic. Pay attention to the following chapters of the JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation:

- HTTPS recording and certificates
- Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

If you will be still experiencing problems check out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.